# Tikzfeynman change blob size/shape

Tags: tikz-feynman

Is there a way to change the size and/or shape of a blob vertex?

I guess a size change could be emulated by making all the arrows shorter, but i would like to know if there is an explicit way.

Additionally, if possible, i would like to change the shape of a blob in such a way that i can effectively take an s-channel propagator (so basically just a particle between two vertices) and cover the whole thing in a blob. This way i can easily switch between two diagrams of identical shape, one with just the blob and then the actual feynman diagram.

Edit:
Original diagram:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{feynman}[medium]
            \vertex(i1) {\(\overline{q}\)};
            \vertex[below=3cm of i1] (i2) {\(q\)};
            \vertex at ($(i1) + (1.25cm, -1.5cm)$) (V1);
            \vertex[right = 3cm of V1] (V2);
            \vertex at ($(V2) + (1.25cm, +1.5cm)$) (W);
            \vertex at ($(V2) + (1.25cm, -1.5cm)$) (Z);
            \diagram* {
                (i1)-- [anti fermion] (V1),
                (i2)-- [fermion] (V1),
                (V1) -- [boson,edge label'=\(W^{\pm}\)] (V2),
                (V2) -- [boson,edge label'=\(W^{\pm}\)] (W),
                (V2) -- [boson,edge label'=\(Z\)] (Z),
            };
        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Current best blob:

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{feynman}[medium]
            \vertex(i1) {\(\overline{q}\)};
            \vertex[below=3cm of i1] (i2) {\(q^\prime\)};
            \vertex[blob] at ($(i1) + (3.75cm, -1.5cm)$) (V) {\makebox[2.cm][l]{}};
            \vertex at ($(V) + (3.75cm, +1.5cm)$) (W) {\(W^{\pm}\)};
            \vertex at ($(V) + (3.75cm, -1.5cm)$) (Z) {\(Z\)};
            \diagram* {
                (i1)-- [anti fermion] (V),
                (i2)-- [fermion] (V),
                (V) -- [boson] (W),
                (V) -- [boson] (Z),
            };
        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch hi, thanks for your comment. I added my original diagram. There i want to replace the middle part with a blob. I also added my bust attempt at doing that as well. However, i would love if i could make that blob oval so that it simply replaces the central propagator.

Answer (score 1):

The shape of `blob` can be changed with `shape=ellipse`, the size can be controlled via `minimum height` and `minimum width` parameters:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{feynman}[medium]
            \vertex(i1) {\(\overline{q}\)};
            \vertex[below=3cm of i1] (i2) {\(q^\prime\)};
            \vertex[blob,shape=ellipse,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=4cm] 
                at ($(i1) + (3.75cm, -1.5cm)$) (V) {};
            \vertex at ($(V) + (3.75cm, +1.5cm)$) (W) {\(W^{\pm}\)};
            \vertex at ($(V) + (3.75cm, -1.5cm)$) (Z) {\(Z\)};
            \diagram* {
                (i1)-- [anti fermion] (V.west),
                (i2)-- [fermion] (V.west),
                (V.east) -- [boson] (W),
                (V.east) -- [boson] (Z),
            };
        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]